# DB design: inventory items derived from other inventory items

Tags: database-design

I'm trying to design an inventory and project management system for a lab. It has a rather tricky element to it that I think separates it from the other "inventory" related questions I've been reading on here. The goal is to be able to track how any physical item in the lab has been used throughout it's lifespan. For general inventory stuff, it's pretty straightforward, and I'm using a superclass/subclass design to break things like chemicals, equipment, etc, out into their own tables while being able to manage them under the same ID/barcode system. What's difficult is that new items can be created from other items. For example, two chemicals can be mixed to create a new solution that might be used later in yet more things, and won't necessarily have all of the same attributes of the original items (e.g., it won't have manufacturer or purchasing data).

I think I've finally figured out a solution that seems reasonable; here's a simplified version of what I'm planning (things like attributes and table names are not finalized)

[image]

Conceptually, "labwork" can lead to the creation of one or more items that need to be inventoried ("labwork items"). In the process, "labwork" can involve the use of one or more items, which I model using a junction table/many-to-many relationship

It's more complicated than other databases I've had to design, so I'm hoping for a sanity check. My question is, is this a reasonable approach to this problem? Does it have any potential downsides I need to be aware of before I commit to fleshing out the details and implementing it?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651424/bill-of-materials-database-model

Comment: @bbaird It's definitely closer to what I'm doing than the other questions I've seen, and the selected answer makes sense to me. The main differences  are that my items have to be spread out across multiple tables, and I also have to be able to track other information about how the items are being used together, so there needs to be at least one other table tied into the junction table somehow. But I am continuing to try and work out if there are other ways to design the model that might be better than what I have